# Dependabot can't update bundler dependency files that reference private git repositories

Tags: ruby, github, bundler, dependabot

I'm trying to follow what Github suggests regarding setting up private bundler repositories for dependabot but for some reason it just doesn't work for me. here is what i did:

1. Created a PAT with access to all my repositories
2. Saved it as `DEPENDABOT_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN` dependabot secret
3. Created a `.github/dependabot.yml` file in my repo with a following contents:

```
version: 2
registries:
  github-octocat:
    type: git
    url: https://github.com
    username: x-access-token
    password: ${{secrets.DEPENDABOT_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}}
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "bundler"
    directory: "/"
    insecure-external-code-execution: allow
    registries:
      - github-octocat
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
```

However, githubs dependabot alert screen keeps saying:

> Dependabot failed to update your dependencies
> The following git repository was unreachable and caused the update to
> fail: xxxxx.
>
> Dependabot can't update bundler dependency files that reference
> private git repositories. Please consider using a git registry.

Comment: *I'm trying to follow what Github suggests* Where are you getting this information?

Comment: @anothermh in the quoted error messsage, the "using a git registry" is linked to a private git registry documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#git

Comment: Are you using `github-octocat`? Because that's just the example, you need to sub in your actual registry. And the registry needs to exist.

Comment: How did you declare your gem in the Gemfile?